# Publishing WSO2 api statisticcs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm following below links for publishing WSO2 statistics. But i'm getting "405 method not allowed" when i login to https://localhost:9443/admin-dashboard. So i'm unable to enable the statistics.

I'm using ws02 API 2.0 and ws02API analytics 2.0. 
Could anyone help me on this.

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

@santosh.a
I assume you have configured apim_wso2metrics_db datasource as common database for wso2am and wso2am-analytics. Next,Follow documentation to configure wso2am-analytics with wso2am-api-manager. [Configuring APIM Analytics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics). Most important Step 2: Edit `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml` and enable analytics and check the DASServerURL and DASRestApiURL, make sure it is pointing to analytics server IP.

Once configuration is enabled. you will be able to see analytics on API Store and API Publisher under statistics sections. You can also go to dashboard by `https://<wso2am-analytics>/portal`